# update_post_meta for repeated custom field

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I have a repeatable custom field made with "cmb2" plugin:

```
$meta_box->add_field( array(
'name' => 'error',
'id' => '_pf_error_log',
'type' => 'text',
'repeatable' => true,
    ),
) );
```

How can i use `update_post_meta` (or any other function) to add a value to a new raw of that repeatable field (without losing the other raws)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the easiest way i found is:

```
$field = get_post_meta( $propostid, '_pf_error_log', true );
$field[] = 'new raw string';
update_post_meta( $propostid, '_pf_error_log', $field );
```

But i will be happy to get a more simple and elegant solution...